# Hide a obligatory parameter when changing radio buttons

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I have some radiobuttons and when I change between them some blocks appear/disappear.

However, if I set parameters as obligatory or required they do not hide unless I fill them. I want to make parameters required but I need to hide them when I change the radiobutton option.

Comment: Please specify whether you're talking of a selection screen or a regular screen.

Comment: Sorry, its in a selection-screen.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a selection screen...

- then loop at your screen and check the value of "YOUR_RADIO_BUTTON"
- enable or disable the blocks

  ```
  AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.

    LOOP AT SCREEN.
  * Radio button parameter = P_RADIO
  *   hide the parameter named "to_hide" 
      IF P_RADIO EQ 'X' AND SCREEN-NAME CS 'TO_HIDE'.
        SCREEN-INPUT = 0.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ENDIF.

  *   display the parameter named "to_hide"
      IF P_RADIO <> 'X' AND SCREEN-NAME CS 'TO_HIDE'.
        SCREEN-INPUT = 1.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ENDIF.

    ENDLOOP.
  ```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but if a parameter inside block is obligatory, you can't hide a block because you need to fill the obligatory parameter.

Comment: The purposed solution does not work because the event AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT will not fire unless the parameter has been filled.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `PARAMETERS ... OBLIGATORY`, this is an unconditional statement - this parameter is required regardless of the other settings. If you need a conditional check, you have to code it for yourself:

```
PARAMETERS p_chkbuk AS CHECKBOX.
PARAMETERS p_bukrs  TYPE bukrs.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_bukrs. 
  IF p_chkbuk = abap_true AND p_bukrs IS INITIAL. 
    MESSAGE 'You need to enter something.' TYPE 'I' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
  ENDIF.
```

Comment: Hmm. Ok. It works, but program ends. I found a way. I can simply put `MESSAGE 'You need to enter something.' TYPE 'I' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.`